# Power Pack for RPi 3

Tags: power-supply, alternative-power

Is there a popular ups power shield that can be used to with RPi 3? 
Ideally I would like to write some code in Python to monitor the battery status of the power pack and also still have access to the GPIO pins. I was curious if anyone has experience with a well documented power shield.

For example, I found this [one](https://www.electrodragon.com/product/raspberry-pi-powerpack-battery-extension-board/) which has no means of measuring the voltage or current usage.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Pi Supply and the Pi Juice hat. They do exactly what your after.

https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-standard

Comment: I saw this before and disrgarded it because it was just too pricey! Is there any alternatives.....?

Comment: Not too sure to be honest. I think the pijuice is considered to be one of the best out there. Looking at battery costs. To buy an 1800mha battery the same size as comes with the basic pi juice they seem to cost around £20-30 by themselves (from a quick look on amazon) so I guess it would depend on what size battery you want. You may end up paying the same price once you bought both a board and a battery. Even if you went for a cheaper board by itself!